# Advance search on database column

Tags: mysql

I have a Table say **tblName** having fields and values

```
| ID  |     Name                 |

| 1   |     Technical University |

| 2   |     XYZ Lab Ltd.         |
```

Now I have to match Name column with the following input values :

```
1- tech univ 
2- tech universities
3- xyz Labs
```

I am not able to write query to get result from the table.
If I match Name column with the input value **tech univ** or **tech universities** then query should response result set Technical University from the tblName.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: sorry, I really can't understand what you need.

Comment: I have a input "tech univ". I want to match this input value with the "Name" column in the table and want record set having Id 1;

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do one thing map name to different names such as

```
ID   I_ID    NAME
1     1      tech university
2     1      tech uni
3     1      tech univs
```

So this table will be link for your search queries I_ID is a foreign key which refers ID in primary table. I guess this could solve your issue and you can define several names for a single name.

Moreover use regular expression for more efficiency and you have to develop a custom function for that though the genral usage of REGEXP is as follows

```
SELECT id, name FROM tblName WHERE name REGEXP 'tech'
```

Please refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm for more on REGEXP

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar: Was this helpful ?

Comment: Good Idea and it will be helpful, but this concept will increase overhead to map data. I dont want to manage mapping.
Is there exist any algo so result can come up?

Comment: Yeah but a direct SQL query won't be able to help. You can try REGEXP, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm but even that won't be able to solve all your issues completely. Either you have to map data or use some intelligent algorithm to find matching words.

Comment: But yes a combination of data mapping and some algorithm would be best.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I had used data mapping and it works.

Comment: @PankajKumar: Cool Man, kindly accept the answer if it was any helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases when you need to match begining of string you can use

```
select * from table where field LIKE 'Hello %'
```

The % sign is a wildcard.

But for the example you need I would rekomend to look on some full text indexing solutions that you put around mysql.

In MS SQL we use a Levenstein Distance function and you could build your own and extend mysql with it.

Here is some examples but I do not know if it will work

https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF

https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF/blob/master/levenshtein.c

Found one that should be pure SQL

http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function

Answer (score 0):

test this it may help

```
SELECT * FROM tblNAME WHERE Name LIKE "%name%";
```